# Flask, Bcrypt - ImportError: No module named ext.bcrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Why the following?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt

 Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ext.bcrypt
```

I have flask-bcrypt installed:

```
pip install Flask-Bcrypt
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Bcrypt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask-Bcrypt) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bcrypt-3.1.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from Flask-Bcrypt) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.10-py2.7.egg (from Flask->Flask-Bcrypt) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask->Flask-Bcrypt) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask->Flask-Bcrypt) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask->Flask-Bcrypt) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi-1.11.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from bcrypt->Flask-Bcrypt) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from bcrypt->Flask-Bcrypt) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MarkupSafe-1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask->Flask-Bcrypt) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser-2.18-py2.7.egg (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt->Flask-Bcrypt) (2.18)
```

This error leaves me nowhere to go.  I followed the docs here:

https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Have you tried `from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt `?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt`.

This is because the flask documentation on flask extensions implies that extensions in the form of `Flask-Foo` and are imported as: `from flask_foo import Foo`

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/extensions/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll edit it with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent flask's update, `from flask.ext.xxx import xxx` has been removed. You should import it directly from its package. And here is a related [issue](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/issues/51).

By the way, this package seems out of date(last updates two years ago).